# What is wrong with this use of Silex' autoloader?

Tags: php, symfony, autoloader, silex

**My application file:**

```
<?php // /src/app.php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../lib/vendor/Sensio/silex.phar';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Foo\Bar;

$app = new Silex\Application(); 
$app['autoloader']->registerNamespace('Foo', __DIR__);
$bar = new Bar();
(...)
```

**My Bar class:**

```
<?php /src/Bar.php

namespace Foo;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;
use Silex\ControllerCollection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Bar implements ControllerProviderInterface { ... }
```

When I do a `$bar = new Bar()` in my `app.php`, I get an error: `Fatal error: Class 'Moken\Classname' not found in (...)/src/app.php on line 11`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `namespace Foo;` you must locate this class in `Foo` directory
Every namespace part is a directory in symfony

If not works, you must show the loader where to find this class
In symfony2 I use for this:

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    // HERE LOCATED FRAMEWORK SPECIFIED PATHS

    // app namespaces
    'Foo' => __DIR__ . '/../src',
));
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I don't know where my head was in this? Maybe too much coffee?

Comment: Please bear in mind that Silex is still under development and doesn't have any stable version. Therefore it could happen that this answer doesn't work anymore with recent Silex changes (It now makes heavy use of Composer)

Answer (score 0):

In your main php file (index.php) you must:

- declare the use of your Controller Provider;
- after creation of your Application object you must register your namespace;
- mount your Controller Provider.

For example (Example\Controllers is the namespace and XyzControllerProvider is the Controller Provider, the url is /my/example):

```php
[...]
// declare the use of your Controller Provider
use Example\Controllers\XyzControllerProvider;
[...]
//after creation of your Application object you must register your namespace;
$app = Application();
$app['autoloader']->registerNamespace('Example', __DIR__.'/src');
[...]
//mount your Controller Provider
$app->mount('/my/example', new Example\Controllers\XyzControllerProvider());
```

the Controller Provider (under src/example/controllers) will be:

```
<?php
namespace Example\Controllers;
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;
use Silex\ControllerCollection;
class XyzControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface {
  public function connect(Application $app) {
    $controllers = new ControllerCollection();
    $controllers->get('/', function (Application $app) {
      return "DONE;"
    });
    return $controllers;
  }
}
```

Comment: Silex has been updated since this anwser and now states: "You tried to access the autoloader service. The autoloader has been removed from Silex. It is recommended that you use Composer to manage your dependencies and handle your autoloading. See http://getcomposer.org for more information." 

To fix this, add the following to your composer.json: `"autoload": { "psr-0": {"Example": "src"} }`

Comment: As far as the autoloader is concerned, I agree. My post and `$app['autoloader']->registerNamespace` was valid some months ago.